# Clarification over internal linkage of inline functions in C

Tags: c, linkage, inline-functions

As the theory goes, `inline` functions have internal/static linkage in C, that is, they are only visible within a single translation unit.
Hence inline function defined in two separate files should not be able to see each other and both will have their own address space.

**I am trying with the following files**

```
***cat a.c*** 

#include <stdio.h>

inline int foo()
{
    return 3;
}

void g()
{
    printf("foo called from g: return value = %d, address = %#p\n", foo(), &foo);
}


***cat b.c***
#include <stdio.h>

inline int foo()
{
    return 4;
}

void g();

int main()
{
    printf("foo called from main: return value = %d, address = %#p\n", foo(), &foo);
    g();
    return 0;
}

gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
gcc -o a.out a.o b.o

b.o: In function `foo':
b.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `foo'
a.o:a.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The above compilation error reflects that **b.c** is able to see the definition of `foo` in **a.c** and compilation is failing (Which should not be the case for internally linked inline functions ).

Please help me to understand if I am missing something.

Edit 1:
Was trying out the theory of this link.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzarg/inline_linkage.htm

Comment: If you don't want your function to be visisble/usable from another file/compilation unit you shouldn't declare them inline, but `static int foo(int bar)`. I C++ inline is sometimes used to declare member functions in a header as inline to make sure they end up in only one compilation unit to prevent multiple definition.

Comment: Try adding `-std=c11` to your compilation commands.

Comment: Since you did not make the functions `static`, the symbol will be visible if the compiler has to generate an actual function. Since you print the address of the function, the compiler must create a function to print the address of in each source file. So you’re bound to get linking errors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Actually, the compiler won't create a function even if one is needed, unless specifically requested. So `&foo` refers to a non-existent external definition of `foo`. That will also give you a linking error, but for an undefined reference, not a duplicate definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** GCC still defaults to its old semantics of `inline`, in which an `inline` function is still compiled as an externally visible entity. Specifying `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` will cause GCC to implement the standard semantics; however, the IBM compiler does not conform to the standard either. So linking will still fail, but with a different error.

---

Since C99, a function declaration with no declared linkage does not generate a function object. The inline definition will only be used with inline substitution, and the compiler is not obliged to perform this optimisation.  It is expected that an external definition of the function exists in some other translation unit, and such a definition must exist if the function object is used, either by taking its address or by being called in a context where the compiler chooses not to perform the inline substitution.

If the inline function is declared with either `static` or `extern`, then a function object is compiled, with the indicated linkage, thereby satisfying the requirement that the function object be defined.

Prior to C99, `inline` was not part of the C standard, but many compilers -- particularly GCC -- implemented it as an extension. In the case of GCC, however, the semantics of `inline` differed slightly from the above exposition.

In C99 (and more recent), an inline function with no linkage specification is only an inline definition ("An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit." §6.7.4p7). But in the GCC extension, an inline function with no linkage specification was given external linkage (just like a non-inline function declaration). GCC then special-cased `extern inline` to mean "do not generate a function object", which is effectively the same as standard C99's handling of an inline function with neither `extern` nor `static` modifiers. See the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html), particularly the last section.

This is only still important because GCC still defaults to using its original `inline` semantics unless you specify that it should conform to some C standard (using, for example, `-std=c11`) or disable the GNU inline semantics using `-fno-gnu89-inline`.

The example code, which I understand is taken from the IBM i7.1 compiler documentation, does not correctly reflect any C standard. The two definitions of `foo` as inline functions do not generate any actual function named `foo`, so the use of `&foo` must refer to some externally-defined `foo`, and there isn't one in the program. GCC will report this issue if you tell it to use C11/C99 semantics:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 a.c b.c
/tmp/ccUKlp5g.o: In function `g':
a.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo'
a.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `foo'
/tmp/cc2hv17O.o: In function `main':
b.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo'
b.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

By contrast, if you ask for Gnu inline semantics, both translation units will define `foo`, and the linker will complain about a duplicate definition:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -fgnu89-inline a.c b.c
/tmp/ccAHHqOI.o: In function `foo':
b.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `foo'
/tmp/ccPyQrTO.o:a.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also note that GCC does not inline any function by default. You must provide some optimization option in order to enable function inlining. If you do so, and you remove the use of the address operator, you can get the program to compile:

```
$ cat a2.c
#include <stdio.h>
inline int foo() { return 3; }
void g() {
    printf("foo called from g: return value = %d\n", foo());
}
$ cat b2.c
#include <stdio.h>
inline int foo() { return 4; }
void g();
int main() {
    printf("foo called from main: return value = %d\n", foo());
    g();
    return 0;
}

$ # With no optimisation, an external definition is still needed:
$ gcc -std=c11 a2.c b2.c
/tmp/cccJV9J6.o: In function `g':
a2.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo'
/tmp/cct5NcjY.o: In function `main':
b2.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ # With inlining enabled, the program works as (possibly) expected:
$ gcc -std=c11 -O a2.c b2.c
$ gcc -std=c11 -O1 a2.c b2.c
$ ./a.out
foo called from main: return value = 4
foo called from g: return value = 3
```

As indicated by the IBM documentation, the rules for C++ are distinct. This program is not valid C++ because the definitions of `foo` in the two translation units differ, but the compiler is not obliged to detect this error and the usual Undefined Behaviour rules apply (i.e., the standard doesn't define what will be printed). As it happens, GCC seems to show the same results as i7.1:

```
$ gcc -std=c++14 -x c++ a.c b.c
$ ./a.out
foo called from main: return value = 3, address = 0x55cd03df5670
foo called from g: return value = 3, address = 0x55cd03df5670
```

Answer (score 0):

Inlining is an optimization and it's at compiler's discretion to do it or not (if at all possible). So it's not guaranteed that the symbol won't be exported in the resulting object file. Use `static` for this purpose.

Comment: Since C99, that is not correct. The compiler may or may not inline the function at any given call site, but it does not give the compiled function external linkage unless specifically requested. See section 6.7.4p6: "An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit."

Comment: @rici Good point, I wasn't aware of that. However, the OP didn't specify which semantics they're using.

Comment: After almost 20 years, it seems reasonable to assume that at least C99 is meant. Anyway, SO assumes that the [tag:c] tag means the current standard, and not a historical artefact: "This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899: **2011** standard"